# strange encoding of an HTTP GET. Lots of square brackets

Tags: encoding

Seeing many packets that appear to be encoded in some fashion which is puzzling me.  Here is a sample :  `GET/somestuff/abc/fergo-scd.pdf0ð[[#6]][[#3]]u[[#29]][[#31]][[#4]] HTTP/1.1. Any help appreciated`

Comment: Where are you seeing these packets exactly? Are you looking at a capture or something? What you have shown is not a valid URL because of the unencoded `ð` character. The rest of the characters are all ASCII characters, so they are *technically* legal, but still odd. If I had to guess (and please, don't make people guess), the real URL is more like `/somestuff/abc/fergo-scd.pdf` but the requester (or the capturer) is corrupting it (maybe with a buffer overflow or something).

Comment: This is being presented by an Imperva WAF.

Comment: The URL shown is basically all there is....there is more of the [[#x]] I did not put them all there.